# Is there a WebGL equivalent of glGenVertexArrays and glBindVertexArrays?

Tags: html, opengl-es, webgl

I'm making a WebGL program and require the GL functions glGenVertexArrays and glBindVertexArrays. Does anybody know if there is an equivalent of these in WebGL? Here's what I have so far:

```
  canvas = document.getElementById("WEB_GL_CANVAS");//Specify the viewing window

  gl = WebGLUtils.setupWebGL(canvas);
  if (!gl)
    alert("WebGL isn't available");

  gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  {
    var color = getRandomColor();
    gl.clearColor((color[0] / 2) + 0.5, (color[1] / 2) + 0.5, (color[2] / 2) + 0.5, 1);
  }
  gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);


  // Create a vertex array object
  GLuint vao;
  gl.genVertexArrays( 1, &vao );//Won't work
  gl.bindVertexArray( vao );//Need a WebGL version
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Only if the [OES_vertex_array_object](http://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/OES_vertex_array_object/) extension is implemented.

However, you don't *need* these functions. You can do just fine without them. You just have to bind your buffers and use glVertexAttribPointer and its ilk before you render a mesh (or set of meshes, or whatever).

Answer (score 6):

As it just so happens, Chrome Canary and Chromium builds from the last week or so have basic support for OES_vertex_array_object now. It's also been available in WebKit for a little while. It's not perfect yet: There's no ANGLE support yet, for example. Still, if you want to develop against the extension you can start doing so now.

I've got quick [blog post and demo](http://blog.tojicode.com/2012/10/oesvertexarrayobject-extension.html) of OES_vertex_array_object in action, if you want to see how it works in the context of WebGL.

Answer (score 2):

The OpenGL 3.0 features will be available within WebGL 2.0, you can check if your browser already support WebGL 2.0 for example here: http://webglreport.com/?v=2, or wathever experimental extension ( like some features form OpenGL 3.0 ) for WebGL 1.0 are available

Answer (score 2):

This is how Emscripten does it:

```
GLctx = canvas.getContext("webgl")
// Extension available from Firefox 25 and WebKit
var vaoExt = GLctx.getExtension('OES_vertex_array_object');
if (vaoExt) {
    GLctx['createVertexArray'] = function() { return vaoExt['createVertexArrayOES'](); };
    GLctx['deleteVertexArray'] = function(vao) { vaoExt['deleteVertexArrayOES'](vao); };
    GLctx['bindVertexArray'] = function(vao) { vaoExt['bindVertexArrayOES'](vao); };
    GLctx['isVertexArray'] = function(vao) { return vaoExt['isVertexArrayOES'](vao); };
}
```